# Find matches between multiple columns in microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I am trying to find matches between multiple columns and if matched then I want to highlight all the matched rows.

The columns can be like this --

1. AAA
2. BBB
3. CCC

Sample columns/rows

```
AAA      BBB      CCC

INS50    FG23     YU44
INS51    FG23     YU44
INS55    FG23     YU45
INS55    FG23     YU46
INS54    FG27     YU49
INS54    FG28     YU49
-----    FG28     YU89
INS59    ----     YU49
```

If we consider the last 3 rows then

INS54 has a relation with FG28 and YU49

FG28 has a relation with YU49 and YU89

Now I want to create matching rows which will have

```
INS54 FG28 YU49 FG27
FG28  YU89 YU49
```

I have no clue how it is possible.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you said to look at just the last three rows, but if you look at the last four, then INS54 also relates to FG27. How do you want to handle that?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I have updated the post. I want all matching columns in a single row.

Comment: I'm not following the result you want.  Can you be more explicit as to how you get to that result?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking, but here is a result that may get you close to where you want to go.

It seems your question has two parts: list the relationships of the items in Column AAA and second, list the relationships of the items in Column BBB.  Consequently the result table below has two sections.

[image]

This formula in E2 and filled down, was used to list the distinct values in Column A:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$9),0,0),0)),"")
```

Similarly this formula in E8 lists the distinct values in Column B:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$7:E7,$B$2:$B$9),0,0),0)),"")
```

The first part of your question seems to want a list of the values in Columns B and C that correspond to the distinct values in Column A.  This array formula in F2 does that:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$C$9,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9=$E2,ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1,""),MOD(COLUMN(),2)+1),TRUNC(COLUMN()/2)-2),"")
```

It must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  After it's entered, it can be filled down and to the right to produce the results in the upper portion of the result table.  Note that some duplicate values are listed.

The second part of your question seems to want a list of the values in Column C that correspond to the distinct values in Column B.  This array formula in F8 is simpler because it has to pick from only one column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$9,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$9=$E8,ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1,""),COLUMN()-5)),"")
```

Assumptions made here are that the first part has a maximum of two related values and the second has 4.  This can be adjusted if necessary.

If you want to pursue this further, duplicates in these results can be removed using formulas similar to the ones listing distinct values in Column E.